# How do I copy old save data to my new Deus Ex installation?

Tags: steam, deus-ex

You know how Steam lets you transfer game saves to a USB stick?
About 5 months ago my PC hard drive got messed up so it had to be replaced, and before that happened, I had saved data from Deus Ex onto my USB stick.
Now, how do I transfer the data on the USB stick to my new hard drive, so it can be found by Deus Ex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy over your save data into where the games are saved. Click on My Computer, go to your C: drive or wherever your program files are located. Click on Program Files (or Program Files x86 if you have it), click on the Steam folder, click on the folder that says userdata, click on the single folder in there then open folder 28050 where the save data should be located then copy over the save data on your USB.

[Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2475067)